# Match an occurrence starting with two or three digits but not containing a specific pattern somewhere

Tags: python, regex

I have the following  lines:

```
 12(3)/FO.2-3;1-2
 153/G6S.3-H;2-3;1-2
 1/G13S.2-3
 22/FO.2-3;1-2
 12(3)2S/FO.2-3;1-2
 153/SH/G6S.3-H;2-3;1-2
 45/3/H/GDP6;2-3;1-2
```

I digits to get a match if at the beginning of the line I find two or three numbers but not one, also if the field contains somewhere the expressions `FO`, `SH`, `GDP` or `LDP` I should not count it as an occurrence. It means, from the previous lines, only get `153/G6S.3-H;2-3;1-2` as a match because in the others either contain `FO`, `SH`, `GDP`, or there is just one digit at the beginning.

I tried using

```
^[1-9][1-9]((?!FO|SH|GDP).)*$
```

I am getting the correct result but I am not sure is correct,  I am not quite expert in regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add any other characters that might be between your starting digits and the things you want to exclude:

Simplified regex:  `^[1-9]{2,3}(?!.*(?:FO|SH|GDP|LDP)).*$`

will only match `153/G6S.3-H;2-3;1-2` from your given data.

Explanation:

```
^[1-9]{2,3}(?!.*(?:FO|SH|GDP|LDP)).*$
-----------  2 to 3 digits or more at start of line  

^[1-9]{2,3}(?!.*(?:FO|SH|GDP|LDP)).*$
            --------------------- any characters + not matching (FO|SH|GDP|LDP)  

^[1-9]{2,3}(?!.*(?:FO|SH|GDP|LDP)).*$
                                  ---  match till end of line
```

The `(?:....)` negative lookbehind must follow exactly, you have other characters between what you do not want to see and your match, hence it is not picking it up.

See https://regex101.com/r/j4SRoQ/1  for more explanations (uses `{2,}`).

---

Full code example:

```
import re

regex = r"^[1-9]{2,3}(?!.*(?:FO|SH|GDP|LDP)).*$"

test_str = r"""12(3)/FO.2-3;1-2
153/G6S.3-H;2-3;1-2
1/G13S.2-3
22/FO.2-3;1-2
12(3)2S/FO.2-3;1-2
153/SH/G6S.3-H;2-3;1-2
45/3/H/GDP6;2-3;1-2"""

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches: 
    print(match.group())
```

Output:

```
153/G6S.3-H;2-3;1-2
```

Comment: according to his post I think he was looking for `{2,3}` not `{2,}`. But other than this this regex looks pretty much like what he was asking for.

Comment: Awesome, thanks people, I got it, and learnt a lot from your replies. :)